# How to increment COUNTER in -exec script?

Tags: shell-script, find, exec

Context: zsh Catalina MacOS:

The executable script **BatesStamp** engages imagemagick to stamp a number to a jpg file:

```
# BatesStamp: OVERWRITES and stamps ONE file with COUNTER  (upper left corner)
# usage  ./BatesStamp  COUNTER  PATH_FILE   
# to be used with find & -exec: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/96239/182280   


COUNTER=$1     # 1st argument = number to be stamped upon .jpg file
PATH_FILE=$2   # 2nd argument = /path_to_file/Filename.jpg

convert $PATH_FILE  -auto-orient -gravity northWest  -font "Arial-Bold-Italic" -pointsize 175 \
   -fill red  -annotate +30+30   "$COUNTER"  $PATH_FILE;
   ((COUNTER++))  #https://stackoverflow.com/a/21035146/4953146
   echo "watermarked i= $COUNTER  $PATH_FILE"
```

The goal is to stamp all .jpg files in directory tree with a unique number.  I believe $COUNTER must be incremented every time it is called: this ensure each file is stamped with a unique number.   The strategy is to traverse all subdirectories with `find` to identify .jpg files and BatesStamp each .jpg file with $COUNTER++.

This script `goBatesStamp.sh` traverses subdirectories to exec each .jpg files to be processed by **BatesStamp**

```
# goBastesStamp.sh
cd /Users/user/Desktop/AITH_USB_Hope_Submitted_MyCloud/PhotoGraphs_Work/A_Building_NoBulkhead. # navigate to top level directory
COUNTER=100   # initialize COUNTER
find /Users/user/Desktop/AITH_USB_Hope_Submitted_MyCloud/PhotoGraphs_Work/A_Building_NoBulkhead -iname "*.jpg" -exec ./BatesStamp $((COUNTER+=1)) {} \;
```

The problem is in the line beginning with the `find` command.  Specifically, the COUNTER does not increment.

Test show that .jpg files are stamped with the number 100
It seams that the $((COUNTER++)) is the problem. What is the proper syntax to increment the COUNTER by one and feed the incremented COUNTER into ./BatesStamp?

Comment: Question Deleted.   BTW, I have discovered that comments may NOT precede `#! /bin/zsh -`  however, that is whole new discussion, but may be helpful for readers.  TL\DR: ensure  `#! /bin/zsh -` is on line 1 with nothing before it.

Comment: Yes, those  `#!` have to be the first two bytes of the file. That is the special signal to the system (not the shell) that the file is a script. As far as the shell is concerned, that line is just a comment as it starts with `#`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the

```
find ... -exec ./BatesStamp $((COUNTER+=1)) {} ';'
```

shell code, that `$((COUNTER+=1))` is expanded by the shell that interprets that command line before invoking the `find` command, so `find` is invoked as:

```
find ... -exec ./BateStamp 101 {} ';'
```

And for each file it finds, it calls `./BateStamp 101 path/to/the/file`.

Even if you changed it to:

```
export COUNTER=100
find ... -exec sh -c 'for f do ./BatesStamp "$((COUNTER+=1))"; done' sh {} +
```

for `find` to start a shell that increments its own `$COUNTER` variable and processes several files in a loop, that would still not work as `find` with `-exec cmd {} +` may still call `cmd` several times, each with a batch of files, and each invocation of that `sh` above would start at 100 again.

Here, you'd need one invocation of sh or some other shell or programming language that processes *all* the files in one invocation.

Since you're already using `zsh`, you should be able to do:

```bsh
#! /bin/zsh -

top=/Users/user/Desktop/AITH_USB_Hope_Submitted_MyCloud/PhotoGraphs_Work/A_Building_NoBulkhead
n=100
for file in $top/**/*.jpg(NDn.); do
  mogrify -auto-orient \
          -gravity northWest \
          -font "Arial-Bold-Italic" \
          -pointsize 175 \
          -fill red \
          -annotate +30+30 $n \
          -- $file &&
    print -ru2 -- $file was watermarked with $n
  (( n++ ))
done
```

Here using `zsh` [recursive globs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing) (where `**/` matches 0 or more levels of subdirectories) instead of `find` to find the `jpg` files (restricted to regular files with the `.` [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) and sorting the input list numerically with `n`¹ instead of processing them in random order like `find` does) and using `mogrify` instead of `convert` as that's the ImageMagick command to edit an image in-place.

Note that for a script to be interpreted by an interpreter other than `sh` when executed directly, you need a she-bang line (`#! /path/to/the/interpreter`) to tell the system which interpreter to use to interpret the contents of the file. Or you can invoke the interpreter manually on the file: `zsh /path/to/that/file`, or have the interactive shell you're currently using (if zsh) interpret it directly with `source /path/to/that/file` or in a subshell so it doesn't alter the environment of your shell session with `(source /path/to/that/file)`.

---

<sup>¹ without the `n` (for `numericglobsort` which is an option that can also be enabled globally) glob qualifier, the sorting is lexical, so `image2.jpg` for instance would come *after* `image10.jpg` because `2` comes after `1` in collation order.</sup>

<sup>² if you wonder about the extra `-` in the `#! /bin/zsh -` shebang, see [Why the "-" in the "#! /bin/sh -" shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/351729)</sup>

Comment: Bon Jour! Thank you for posting a promising solution.  I was excited to test the glob and [posted results and questions in a new question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678384/interpreting-globbing-wildcards)   Your experience and insight are appreciated.

Comment: @gatorback, see edit, in particular the part about how to make sure the script is interpreted by zsh and not by sh. I also gave links to relevant parts of zsh's manual.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  In order to simplify the matter, I have posted a screenshot: I believe that it confirms that `zSh` and not BASH is engaged.   I am struggling (not successful)  in globbing jpg files as shown in the new posting and willing to learn / follow instructions.

Comment: @gatorback, no, it does confirm you executed the script directly and that it was interpreted by `sh`, likely because you didn't add a `#! /bin/zsh -` line at the top.

Comment: Giving a `sh` extension to a `zsh` script is also quite misleading. In any case, the extension is not needed and not relevant nor used to determine what shell / programming language interpreter to use to interpret the script.

Comment: I just realized that globbing must be case insensitive to collect .jpg .JPG jpeg and .JPEG.  and posted a [question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/678439/182280)