# zsh case-insensitive globbing

Tags: zsh, wildcards, case-sensitivity

Context: macOS Catalina (zsh)

This script is to process all JPEG files.   This script does not process .JPG files, however it does process .jpg files.

```
top=/Users/user/Desktop/
for file in $top/**/*.jp*g(NDn.); do      #selects filetypes: .jpg .jpeg 
  mogrify -auto-orient \
          -gravity northWest \
          -font "Arial-Bold-Italic" \
          -pointsize 175 \
          -fill red \
          -annotate +30+30 $n \
          -- $file &&
  echo  $file "was watermarked with" $n | tee -a forLooplog.txt
  (( n++ ))
done
```

How can the second line be modified to be case insensitive and trap .JPG .JPEG files?

Comment: I don't see why you can't use `$top/**/*.(jpg|jpeg|JPG|JPEG)` if that is what you actually mean.  If you use `jp*g` and then make that case-insensitive, you'll match `.jPEEg`, and `.jp.rated-g` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Especially for your case where the glob is `$top/**/*.jpg`, I would **not** turn the `caseglob` option off (same as turning `nocaseglob` on¹) globally, as that affects all path components in glob patterns:

```
$ top=a zsh +o caseglob -c 'print -rC1 --  $top/*.jpg'
a/foo.jpg
a/foo.JPG
a/FOO.jpg
a/FOO.JPG
A/foo.jpg
A/foo.JPG
A/FOO.jpg
A/FOO.JPG
```

See how it did find all the `jpg` and `JPG` files in `$top` (`a`), but also the ones in an unrelated directory (`A`) which just happened to have the same name but in upper case. Even if you don't have such directories, zsh will still look for them which means it needs to list the contents of every directory that makes up the components of `$top` making that glob expansion more costly.

IMO, that `nocaseglob` option is better left forgotten. It was only added to zsh for compatibility with `bash`², and there most likely added to make the life of users of systems like Cygwin / macos that have case insensitive filesystem APIs easier.

Instead, I'd used  the `(#i)` glob operator (with `extendedglob`) where you can specify which part of which glob should be case insensitive (similar to the `~(i)` of ksh93):

```
set -o extendedglob # needed for (#i)
for file in $top/**/*.(#i)jp(e|)g(NDn.); do
```

Or you can always do:

```
for file in $top/**/*.[jJ][pP]([eE]|)[gG](NDn.); do
```

as you would in `sh` or any shell without case-insensitive glob operators.

Also note that `*.jp(|e)g` instead of `*.jp*g` which would match on filenames such as `my.jpeg.import.log` for instance.

---

<sup>¹ or `CASEGLOB`, `CASE_GLOB`, `C_A_se_G_lob`, case and underscores are ignored in option names, and the support of `no` to turn an option off is to try and accommodate the mess with POSIX sh options (and other shells' including zsh itself) where some options are named with a `no` prefix and some without for no immediately obvious reason.</sup>

<sup>² though the bash behaviour is different (and preferable IMO, at least on systems with case sensitive file names) in this instance in that `a/*.jpg` would only find `jpg`/`JPG` files in `a`, not `A` as it only does case insensitive matching for *path components* that do have glob operators (`[a]/*.jpg` would also find the `jpg`/`JPG` files in `A`).</sup>

Comment: Do you recommend using the two-line solution (#i) over the one-line?  Why?

Comment: I don't recommend either. I just mention two alternatives, one where you use a dedicated zsh-specific operator, one where you explicitly list the case variants for each character.