# Enumeration Stamping pdf pages with Imagemagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

A .pdf file has 100 pages of images.

The goal is to enumerate pages 81-90 in the upper left hand corner.   I have been able to enumerate .jpg (Raster) images with imagemagick

```
top=/Users/user/Desktop/AITH_USB_Hope_Submitted_MyCloud/Photographs_ForLoopCaseInsesntive
n=100
echo $top
cp /dev/null forLooplog.txt
echo `date` | tee -a $top/forLooplog.txt
for file in $top/**/*.[jJ][pP]([eE]|)[gG](NDn.); do   https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678469/182280
  mogrify -auto-orient \
          -gravity northWest \
          -font "Arial-Bold-Italic" \
          -pointsize 175 \
          -fill red \
          -annotate +30+30 $n \
          -- $file &&
  echo  $file "was watermarked with" $n | tee -a $top/forLooplog.txt
  (( n++ ))
done
echo `date` | tee -a forLooplog.txt
```

It is my understanding the pdf is a Vector format and suspect that it may be necessary to convert the pdf page to a matrix (Raster).

GOAL: loop through pages of the pdf file and enumerate the page in a similar manner.  I have had difficulty finding examples that could be cobbled together to reproduce results similar to the script above.

How would one script a similar algorithm that would enable Imagemagick to loop through each page of a pdf  fileand label / stamp as shown in the above example?

Guidance are appreciated / examples are preferred.  Thank you

Comment: Just seeing “echo \`date\` | tee -a …” is making me wonder about your shell scripting…

Comment: @jsbillings I have limited experience with shell scripting and appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please ask a question.  Give errors where you encounter them.