# How to replace both lower and uppercase extensions with Parameter Expansion?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I'm converting `doc` files to `txt` using `catdoc` on Linux. To keep the same file name as output file I'm replacing the `.doc` extension with `.txt` using parameter expension. But there are many doc files ending on `.DOC`. How to make the `.doc` in `${filename%.doc}.txt` case insentive while keeping the capitals in the filename itself? I can't use `${filename%.*}.txt` because some files have dots in the filename

My current code:

```
find "${COMPANYPATH}" -iname '*.doc' | while read -r file; do
    echo "${file}"
    filename=$(basename "${file}")
    path="${file%/*}/"
    mkdir -p "${OUTPUTPATH}/DOC/${path#$COMPANYPATH/}"
    catdoc "${file}" >> "${OUTPUTPATH}/DOC/${path#$COMPANYPATH}${filename%.doc}.txt"
done
```

input

```
/home/user/test/2218-0/test.doc
/home/user/test/2218-0/Test2.DOC
```

Expected output

```
/home/user/output/test/DOC/2218-0/test.txt
/home/user/output/test/DOC/2218-0/Test2.txt
```

**There are no duplicated files.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can make the pattern match in `${filename%.doc}` case-insensitive in Bash. [You could do it zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/678439/170373), with `${filename%(#i).doc}` (requires `setopt extendedglob` enabled) or `ksh93` with `${filename%~(i:.doc)}`. Bash's `nocasematch` doesn't help, it only works in `case` and `[[ .. ]]` constructs.

In any POSIX shell, there's always the workaround of explicitly listing both uppercase and lowercase characters with `${filename%.[dD][oO][cC]}`. Or just remove the three last characters with `${filename%.???}`, knowing `find` only gives you the correct ones.

Then again `${filename%.*}` should only remove the shortest matching part, so that should also not be a problem. (`%%` would remove the longest.)

zsh:

```
% setopt extendedglob
% filename=foo.bar.DoC
% echo ${filename%.(#i)doc}.txt
foo.bar.txt
```

sh/Bash:

```
$ filename=foo.bar.DoC
$ echo "${filename%.[dD][oO][cC]}.txt"
foo.bar.txt
$ echo "${filename%.*}.txt"
foo.bar.txt
```

Comment: Or since the `find` will only output values with 3-letter suffixes, `${filename%.???}`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, oh yes, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You don't. Just remove the extension entirely instead:

```
find "${COMPANYPATH}" -iname '*.doc' | while read -r file; do
    echo "${file}"
    filename=$(basename "${file}")
    name="${file%.*}"
    path="${file%/*}"
    noComPath="${path#$COMPANYPATH/}"
    mkdir -p "${OUTPUTPATH}/DOC/$noComPath"
    catdoc "${file}" >> "${OUTPUTPATH}/DOC/$noComPath/$name.txt"
done
```

The expression `name="${file%.*}"` will set the variable `name` to the name of the file with the anything from the last `.` to the end removed. If there are many `.`, only the last is removed:

```
$ foo=file.foo.bar.DoC
$ echo "${foo%.*}"
file.foo.bar
```

And here is a more robust version that can deal with arbitrary file names (your would fail if a file name contains a newline character for instance):

```
LC_ALL=C find "${COMPANYPATH}" -iname '*.doc' -type f -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    printf>&2 'Processing "%s"\n' "${file}"
    basename="${file##*/}"
    dirname="${file%/*}"
    rootname="${basename%.*}"
    targetdir=${OUTPUTPATH}/DOC/${dirname#"${COMPANYPATH}/"}
    mkdir -p -- "${targetdir}" &&
      catdoc -- "${file}" >> "${targetdir}/${rootname}.txt"
  done
```

Comment: Thanks you for your recommendation on a more robust version. I decided to mark @ilkkachu his answer as the right one because it fits the initial question more

Comment: @unixcandles of course, it is a better answer that focuses on exactly what you need! In any case, there's never a reason to justify which answer you choose, it is entirely up to you :).